# Android Game Loop Logic Confusion

Tags: java, android, game-loop

I've had a look around online and can't find a valid answer to the following.
In Android, when using a SurfaceView and Thread to facilitate a game loop, usually your onDraw call runs perpetually. This is fine for rendering things but since your game logic is also in this loop (checking for things like game over conditions, mouse events etc), what if you have code that only needs to run once?

Since I feel this is unclear, let me give an example.

I am making a game with several states. When the state is set to title, the game loop does the titleScreenRendering() method which has an image that alphas from 0 to 1 fading in; something like a splash screen. Since this call is in the game loop, "titleScreenRendering" gets called 9999999 times and so does the image fading logic and this obviously does not work.

One way i've found which feels like a hack is to just make a boolean and set it to false the first time the game loop runs the method, so that in the 999999 subsequent calls at least that part of the code is no longer run.

What am I doing wrong here? Is my design wrong, and if it is why do 99% of Android game tutorials seem to advocate this method? Please let there be some clever fellow who can point me in the right direction. I want to do this myself but i'm very tempted to just use a library.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented my game in Android in a bit similar manner that what you are doing. I have added a "layer" in the engine which simulates a screen. In the game core loop I paint and update only the screen. This way if I have several screens like menu etc, I only paint and update one of them at the time. The engine has a reference to current screen.

It is also possible to divide the screen to states. The state or state machine then knows what kind of calculation or painting should be done in that particular state of the screen.

Eventually you need to have somewhere some kind of logic (control flow) but I would try to encapsulate the logic to classes responsible for certain things. This way it's easier to understand and refactor the game later.

Answer (score 0):

Your using logic to do exactly what you want to do in a way that doesn't really effect performance. I don't see a problem here.

If this is related to your state machine, just make sure switching back to the state(title?) from anything else resets the boolean.

Just create a conditional that decides if the function runs or not. These kinds of first-run methods exist and are common. Typically, especially in java, you can just do all of your first-run stuff within your constructor. But that isn't always optional or optimal.

```
if( shouldInutRun != false ) {
    initTitleScreen();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. So you suggest just using a boolean to limit the execution of parts of my code to once and letting the loop render endlessly? I feel as though the game loop should not work like this. Why would you call something like "initTitleScreen" 9999x times and not just once? I think this is an error in design by me

Answer (score 0):

You could have your game logic on another thread if you choose. Calculating logic on the graphics thread is fine for small games, but if your game has a lot of different sections that don't need to be run every time, you will be wasting some, albeit usually inconsequential, CPU power to check each condition every time you run. In addition to that, it doesn't look very nice to have a onDraw method thats five pages long for every step of your game. If your game has a lot of logic, this could also slow down the rendering, as the system waits until onDraw() has returned before displaying anything on the surface.

Consider having a Scene class that holds just graphics information, like what needs to be drawn where. From the onDraw method, construct your SurfaceView from the information in the Scene class. From the game logic thread, process user input, and sprite locations etc... and construct/modify the Scene object.

One last thing, I'd also recommend, if you choose to do this, to have synchronization between the drawing thread and the logic thread, this way you won't get any halfway-modified Scene objects.